# Loading Data from Remote Machine to Hive Database

Tags: hive, load, import-from-csv

I have a CSV file stored on a remote machine. I need to load this data into my Hive Database which is installed in different machine. Is there any way to do this?

note: I am using Hive 0.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Hive basically applies a schema to data that resides in HDFS, you'll want to create a location in HDFS, move your data there, and then create a Hive table that points to that location. If you're using a commercial distribution, this may be possible from Hue (the Hadoop User Environment web UI).

Here's an example from the command line.

Create csv file on local machine:

```
$ vi famous_dictators.csv
```

... and this is what the file looks like:

```
$ cat famous_dictators.csv 
1,Mao Zedong,63000000
2,Jozef Stalin,23000000
3,Adolf Hitler,17000000
4,Leopold II of Belgium,8000000
5,Hideki Tojo,5000000
6,Ismail Enver Pasha,2500000
7,Pol Pot,1700000
8,Kim Il Sung,1600000
9,Mengistu Haile Mariam,950000
10,Yakubu Gowon,1100000
```

Then `scp` the csv file to a cluster node:

```
$ scp famous_dictators.csv hadoop01:/tmp/
```

`ssh` into the node:

```
$ ssh hadoop01
```

Create a folder in HDFS:

```
[awoolford@hadoop01 ~]$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /tmp/famous_dictators/
```

Copy the csv file from the local filesystem into the HDFS folder:

```
[awoolford@hadoop01 ~]$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/famous_dictators.csv /tmp/famous_dictators/
```

Then login to hive and create the table:

```
[awoolford@hadoop01 ~]$ hive

hive> CREATE  TABLE `famous_dictators`(
    >   `rank` int, 
    >   `name` string,
    >   `deaths` int)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    >   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    >   LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
    > LOCATION
    >   'hdfs:///tmp/famous_dictators';
```

You should now be able to query your data in Hive:

```
hive> select * from famous_dictators;
OK
1   Mao Zedong  63000000
2   Jozef Stalin    23000000
3   Adolf Hitler    17000000
4   Leopold II of Belgium   8000000
5   Hideki Tojo 5000000
6   Ismail Enver Pasha  2500000
7   Pol Pot 1700000
8   Kim Il Sung 1600000
9   Mengistu Haile Mariam   950000
10  Yakubu Gowon    1100000
Time taken: 0.789 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)
```

Comment: I'm delighted to hear that, Sam. Great job!